# How to implement std::move() when dealing with C library objects

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Lets say we have the following code

```
class Image
{
public:
    Image(const std::string & path)
    {
        pBitmap_ = FreeImage_Load( imageFormat, pathname.c_str() );
    }
    ~Image()
    {
        FreeImage_Unload(pBitmap_);
    }
private:
    FIBITMAP * pBitmap_;

};
```

How would Image(Image && rhs) be implemented?
after moving the dtor is still called on rhs, which will not give the intended effect?
I suppose something like

```
Image::Image( Image && rhs )
{
    pBitmap_ = std::move(rhs.pBitmap_);
            rhs.pBitmap_ = nullptr;
}
```

and then checking against null in the dtor should do the trick, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to *not do it yourself*, but use the library facilities of the language:

```
struct FiBitmapDeleter {
    void operator()(FIBITMAP *pBitmap) { FreeImage_Unload(pBitmap); }
};

class Image {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<FIBITMAP, FiBitmapDeleter> pBitmap_;
};
```

Now you don't need to write destructor, move constructor, or move assignment operator.  Also your class automatically has its copy constructor and copy assignment operator deleted, so you don't need to worry about those either, completing the Rule of Five.

An alternative is to specialize `default_delete`, meaning that you don't need to supply the deleter type to `unique_ptr`:

```
namespace std {
    template<> struct default_delete<FIBITMAP> {
        void operator()(FIBITMAP *pBitmap) { FreeImage_Unload(pBitmap); }
    };
}
std::unique_ptr<FIBITMAP> pBitmap_;
```

This has global effects, so you should only do it if you're confident that yours is the only code in the program that might perform this specialization.

Comment: As a side note, in practice you still might have to write the move members (but now they're just trivial to implement) if your compiler doesn't generate them automatically (though by standard it should), as is the case with MSVC. But of course great answer.

Comment: There is a bit more on this exact topic [here](http://rmartinho.github.com/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero.html).